# Возможно ли пересоздание объекта в методе расширения?

Tags: c#

Имеется вот такой код, для примера:

```
class SomeHelper {
    public static bool ReCreateIfNeed(ref SomeClass obj, int p1, int p2) {
        if (obj == null) {
            obj = new SomeClass(p1, p2);
            return true;
        }
        if(obj.p1 != p1 || obj.p2 != p2) {
            obj.Resize(p1, p2);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Вызов происходит подобным образом

```
SomeClass obj;
// очень много кода с разными вариантами
SomeHelper.ReCreateIfNeed(ref obj, int param1, int param2);
```

А хочется как-то так:

```
SomeClass obj;
// очень много кода с разными вариантами
obj.ReCreateIfNeed(int param1, int param2);
```

Получится ли так? И можно ли вообще как-то так?

Comment: А почему ключевого слово `ref` а не `this`?

Comment: @yolosora, потому что сейчас это обычный статический метод

Answer (score 1, accepted):

До C# 7.2 нельзя было использовать `ref` рядом с `this` в методах расширения.

Начиная с C# 7.2 [такая возможность появилась](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.2/readonly-ref.md#refin-extension-methods), но распространяется она только на типы-значения.

Это позволяет избежать копирования при работе с большими структурами, а так же появляется возможность делать методы расширения, которые могут менять переданную структуру.

---

Так как в вопросе речь идет о классе, то такой вызов не поддерживается.